# how typedef works internally (at compiler level)?

Tags: c, typedef

i come across this question in an interview recently. they asked me when we create new user defined Type using Typedef (Like typedef unsigned char CHAR) what happens internally??

Comment: What does "internally" mean? What does "int" mean internally, at memory level?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Typedefs are simply making aliases between identifiers. Nothing to do with memory.

Comment: typedefs don't descend to memory level.

Comment: Nothing happens in the generated executable, if that's what you're wondering. A typedef defines a type alias; this is only useful during compilation. Internally, the compiler keeps track of the type underneath a typedef, but that's mostly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally there will happen nothing because it is only the information for the compiler that you introduced some alias for another type.

According to the C Standard (6.7.8 Type definitions)

> 3. ...A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified.

Take into account that opposite to C++ in C there is no such a notion as the user defined type. The C Standard does not use such a term.

To define a user type you have to specify its behaviour. The C language does not allow to specify behaviours of types.:)

As for the "memory level" then the only consequence is that you can forget what actual type this typedef alias denotes.:)